# Calling form.change(fieldName, value) in another field does not change fieldName Field

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-final-form

I am trying to use the `Form` component with `subscription={{ submitting: true, pristine: true }}` so it does not re-render the whole form with each change. I have a field that changes the value of another one in the form. I expect the `Field` component to be subscribed to changes to its name value. In this case it does not change and I need to wrap the field with `FormSpy`. This is not the best solution, since `FormSpy` cannot subscribe to a single value, and re-renders its children on every change in `values`.

This is the code working, but it should not need `FormSpy`:

```
export const CountryForm = ({ regions, countries }) => (
  <Form
    onSubmit={submittedData => {
      console.log({ submittedData })
    }}
    subscription={{ submitting: true, pristine: true }}
    render={({ handleSubmit, form }) => (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormLabel>Regions</FormLabel>
        <FormField
          name="region"
          render={({ input, ...props }) => (
            <Select
              options={regions}
              input={{
                ...input,
                onChange: (selectedRegion: string) => {
                  input.onChange(selectedRegion)

                  const formState = form.getState()
                  const selectedCountries: string[] = formState.values.countries || []
                  const countriesFiltered = filter(countries, {
                    region: selectedRegion,
                  })

                  forEach(countriesFiltered, country => {
                    if (selectedCountries.indexOf(country.code) === -1)
                      selectedCountries.push(country.code)
                  })

                  form.change('countries', selectedCountries)
                },
              }}
              {...props}
            />
          )}
        />
        <FormLabel>Countries</FormLabel>
        <FormSpy subscription={{ values: true }}>
          {() => (
            <Field
              name="countries"
              render={props => <Select options={countries} {...props} />}
            />
          )}
        </FormSpy>
      </form>
    )}
  />
)
```

Without the `FormSpy` component it does not refresh `countries` field on `region` field change.

My problem is that I do not know if this is a bug when using `subscription` property in `Form` or I am using the `form.onChange` function incorrectly.

Comment: It really should rerender the "countries" field. It's not entirely obvious what the problem is from this code. I could help you a lot better if you could provide a sandbox link. Also, the process of making one might reveal the solution.

Comment: You are completely right my friend: codesandbox.io/s/objective-fog-5hjt9?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely an error on my code, `Field` component is subscribed to changes on its own name